# GET all collections of NFT, API, Magic eden

Tags: data, magiceden, on-chain, api

Good morning. I'm looking to make a small coinmarketcap, but from solana nfts, like solsniper or matricnft. I have tried with the magic eden api but it does not give many options, get /collections can only return 500 collections and in general, the api falls short. I have also tried with the moralis and quicknode api, but they have few methods compared to eth and they don't work for this.

https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=500

https://api.magiceden.dev/

Do you know any api that can help me for this project? Any way to read the onchain data? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so you can make a function that requests the 500 and then adds them all to a list. you then add 500 to the offset of the request and keep repeating until the request returns empty. here's an example in python

```
async def all_projects() -> dict:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        output = {}
        offset = 0
        while True:
            url = f"http://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset={offset}&limit=500"
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                resp = await response.json()
            if resp == []:
                return output
            else:
                for obj in resp:
                    output.update({obj["name"].lower(): obj["symbol"].lower()})
                offset += 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you looked at this API: https://docs.hyperspace.xyz/hype/developer-guide/overview

I didn't use it yet, but it looks like a good option.